# how to use two validator in datetime picker

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker, momentjs

I am using [Date time picker](https://github.com/bevacqua/rome) on my site .Every thing  is working fine but i want to use two validator one is i want to disable **Saturday sunday** and the **Us holidays** . Here is function i am using 
following is working to disable the saturday sunday

```
rome(mm,{
  dateValidator: function (d) {

   var dates= moment(d).day() !== 0 && moment(d).day() !== 6 ;
return dates;
 },
//dateValidator: rome.val.except(dates_holidays),
min: s,
max: m,
time: false
});
```

following is working for holidays ,

```
rome(mm,{
     dateValidator: rome.val.except(['2015-04-20', '2015-04-18', '2015-04-15']),
    min: s,
    max: m,
    time: false
    });
```

But i want to use both . please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dateValidator: function(date) {
    var weekday = moment(date).day();
    return weekday != 0 && weekday != 6 && rome.val.except(['2015-04-20', '2015-04-18', '2015-04-15'])(date);
}
```

`rome.val.except()` returns a function, so you just call that in combination with your checks of the day of week.